# Escape Quote - javascript, struts 2

Tags: javascript, struts2, escaping

I read some struts2 variable in javascript as follows:

```
<javascript type="text/javascript"> 
var data='<s:property value="simulationInfos"/>';
<javascript>
```

If my simulationInfos contains single quote ', I get the error : unexpected identifier.

therefore, I tried to escape the quote as follows:

```
var data='<s:property value="simInfos" escapeJavaScript="true"/>';
and var data='<s:property value="simInfos" escapeHTML="true"/>';
```

I get the error: Attribute escapeJavaScript (or escapeHTML) invalid for tag property according to TLD.

Any Idea?

Comment: Depends on the version of struts2 you are using look to the struts2-core-VERSION jar to determine those properties are available. You'll notice that the support url contains the version number, change that to reflect the version you are currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the single quote appear? In the value, I'm assuming?

In that case, in your javascript before you perform the struts2 operation, do run this code on the value. This is a regular expression to remove quotations for javascript.

```
 var escapedString = valueString.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1"); //note, includes double quotes
```

If you need to keep the quotes as URL encoded, do this

```
 var escapedString = valueString.replace(/(['])/g, "&apos;");
```

Comment: Yes, the single quote appears in the value "simulationInfos".  I run your code In javascript to know, what it makes, I have notices, that  it converts A'+B to A\'+B, what do you mean with: it removes quotation?. I did the same in java: valueString.replace("'", "\\'") and it workds, thanx :)

Comment: ['"] removes single and double quotes. What you've done for your final solution is an escape sequence to escape the slash and the quote- so both appear in the final string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the inbuilt `escapeJavascript` of `<s:property>`, then upgrade to [2.2.1](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/property.html) Also in JavaScript, you can easily avoid `unexpected identifier` error if you had used double quotes.

```
var data = "<s:property value="simulationInfos"/>";
```